# Fixed size cell in SwiftUI Grid

Tags: swiftui

I would like to have a grid with fixed size square cells.  Trying two approaches as shown below.

Using `Cell1` behavior is as expected but the size of the square is fixed at what seems to be about 10x10.  The results with `Cell2` are completely unexpected.  It seems like the grid is still laid out using 10x10-ish cells (the yellow overlay) but the actual path starting at the 0,0 of each cell is 50x50 (hence the black bands right and bottom).  If I remove the `.fixedSize()` in `Cell2` than no black bands but i get a grid that scales )with a variable aspect ration of each cell to boot) to fill the available space.

What am I missing here?  How to achieve what I want -- that every cell of the grid is a square with some size I control?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Cell1: View { var body: some View { Rectangle().fixedSize() }}
struct Cell2: View {
  var body: some View {
    Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)).fixedSize()
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var cfg = (groupSize: 5, rows: 2, columns: 3)

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Grid(horizontalSpacing: -2, verticalSpacing: -2) {
        ForEach(0..<cfg.rows, id: \.self) { _ in
          GridRow {
            ForEach(0..<cfg.columns, id: \.self) { _ in
              Grid(horizontalSpacing: -1, verticalSpacing: -1) {
                ForEach(0..<cfg.groupSize, id: \.self) { _ in
                  GridRow {
                    ForEach(0..<cfg.groupSize, id: \.self) { _ in
                      Cell1().overlay(.yellow).border(.black, width: 1)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }.border(.black, width: 2)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      Grid(horizontalSpacing: -2, verticalSpacing: -2) {
        ForEach(0..<cfg.rows, id: \.self) { _ in
          GridRow {
            ForEach(0..<cfg.columns, id: \.self) { _ in
              Grid(horizontalSpacing: -1, verticalSpacing: -1) {
                ForEach(0..<cfg.groupSize, id: \.self) { _ in
                  GridRow {
                    ForEach(0..<cfg.groupSize, id: \.self) { _ in
                      Cell2().overlay(.yellow).border(.black, width: 1)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }.border(.black, width: 2)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-draw-a-checkerboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using `Cell1` behavior is as expected but the size of the square is fixed at what seems to be about 10x10.

That's because you used `.fixedSize()`. A `Rectangle` has no intrinsic size; it accepts whatever size its parent proposes. But the `.fixedSize()` modifier hides the parent's proposed size and passes down `nil` as the proposed size. When SwiftUI needs to return a size but the proposal is nil, [it returns 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/proposedviewsize/replacingunspecifieddimensions(by:)).

> The results with `Cell2` are completely unexpected. It seems like the grid is still laid out using 10x10-ish cells (the yellow overlay) but the actual path starting at the 0,0 of each cell is 50x50 (hence the black bands right and bottom).

That is exactly what is happening.

Oddly, a `Path` *also* has no intrinsic size. [`Path`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path) conforms to `View` by way of conforming to [`Shape`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape#). As of late 2022, `Shape` requires a [`sizeThatFits(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/sizethatfits(_:)-9r323) method, which we can use to demonstrate that `Path` has no intrinsic size:

```
; xcrun swift repl
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.8 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.1 clang-1403.0.22.11.100).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> import SwiftUI
  2> let p = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
p: SwiftUI.Path = {
  storage = rect {
    rect = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 50, height = 50))
  }
}
  3> p.sizeThatFits(.zero)
$R0: CGSize = (width = 0, height = 0)
  4> p.sizeThatFits(.unspecified)
$R1: CGSize = (width = 10, height = 10)
  5> p.sizeThatFits(.init(width: 67, height: 89))
$R2: CGSize = (width = 67, height = 89)
```

I think this is probably a bug in `Path` that Apple cannot fix now without breaking existing apps.

So when you use your `Cell2`, which applies `.fixedSize()` to a `Path`, `Cell2` reports a size of 10x10. But SwiftUI doesn't clip a `View`'s rendering to its bounds by default, so the `Path` in `Cell2` still draws a 50-point square. If you add the `.clipped()` modifier, SwiftUI clips the rendering (by discarding the excess pixels, not by scaling down the `Path`):

```
struct Cell2: View {
  var body: some View {
    Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
      .clipped()
      .fixedSize()
  }
}
```

> How to achieve what I want -- that every cell of the grid is a square with some size I control?

Replace the `.fixedSize()` modifier in `Cell1` with a `.frame` modifier that specifies the size you want. For example, if you want 20-point squares:

```
struct Cell1: View {
  var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
      .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.  I had just figured out that I needed `.frame()` based on the example in the other comment but it's good to understand how and why things work.  I had researched the docs well, I thought, incl. attempting a custom payout protocol, but hadn't come around to understand how it all ties together.  Cheers!